# Combining X number of Update Statements in one Update Statement

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update

I have three update statements in a script that brings in data from another table and populates TOCTASK accoring to matching C, I values.

TOCTASK is large and each statement takes a long time to run, I was wondering is there a way of combinding the 3 statements into one overall update statement

*This will be done on an Oracle database*

Example of the update statements:

```
UPDATE TOCTASK
SET TOCTASK.COL1 =
  (SELECT VM_TEMP_TOCTASK.COL1
  FROM VM_TEMP_TOCTASK
  WHERE VM_TEMP_TOCTASK.C = TOCTASK.C
  AND VM_TEMP_TOCTASK.I = TOCTASK.I
  );


UPDATE TOCTASK
SET TOCTASK.COL2 =
  (SELECT VM_TEMP_TOCTASK.COL2
  FROM VM_TEMP_TOCTASK
  WHERE VM_TEMP_TOCTASK.C = TOCTASK.C
  AND VM_TEMP_TOCTASK.I = TOCTASK.I
  );


UPDATE TOCTASK
SET TOCTASK.COL3 =
  (SELECT VM_TEMP_TOCTASK.COL3
  FROM VM_TEMP_TOCTASK
  WHERE VM_TEMP_TOCTASK.C = TOCTASK.C
  AND VM_TEMP_TOCTASK.I = TOCTASK.I
  );
```

Any help would be great

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the entire tuple at once:

```
UPDATE TOCTASK
    SET (COL1, COL2, COL3) =
         (SELECT tt.COL1, tt.COL2, tt.COL3
          FROM VM_TEMP_TOCTASK tt
          WHERE tt.C = TOCTASK.C AND tt.I = TOCTASK.I
         );
```

Note that an index on `VM_TEMP_TOCTASK(C, I)` would probably also help performance.

And, this code will set non-matching values to `NULL`.  Often such a subquery is used in conjunction with `EXISTS`:

```
UPDATE TOCTASK
    SET (COL1, COL2, COL3) =
         (SELECT tt.COL1, tt.COL2, tt.COL3
          FROM VM_TEMP_TOCTASK tt
          WHERE tt.C = TOCTASK.C AND tt.I = TOCTASK.I
         );
    WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM VM_TEMP_TOCTASK tt
                  WHERE tt.C = TOCTASK.C AND tt.I = TOCTASK.I
                 );
```

Comment: Just wondering, the above code, if say col1 and col3 had data but col2 was null on that record. What would happen ?

Comment: @Jamiex304 . . . If `col2` were `NULL`, then it would be set to `NULL` in `TOCTASK`.  `col2` is not part of the matching condition, so the rows would still match.

Comment: Thanks for the followup